# python import circular dependency (and perhaps function declaration)

Tags: python, import, circular-dependency

Hello I did got into circular dependency what is not refactori-zable other than doubling code.

I have something like this (only much more complex):

myParser.py:

```
import sys
import main                      #comment this to make it runnable
def parseEvnt():
    sys.stdout.write("evnt:")
    main.parseCmd(1)             #comment this to make it runnable
```

tbl.py:

```
import myParser
tblx = {
       1:("cmd",),
       2:("evnt",myParser.parseEvnt),
       }
```

main.py:

```
import tbl
def parseCmd(d):
    print(tbl.tblx[d][0])
data=[1,2]
for d in data:
    if(d<2):
        parseCmd(d)
    else:
        fce = tbl.tblx[d][1]
        fce()
```

Obvious error I'm getting is:

```
File "D:\Data\vbe\workspace\marsPython\testCircular2\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tbl
  File "D:\Data\vbe\workspace\marsPython\testCircular2\tbl.py", line 1, in <module>
    import myParser
  File "D:\Data\vbe\workspace\marsPython\testCircular2\myParser.py", line 2, in <module>
    import main
  File "D:\Data\vbe\workspace\marsPython\testCircular2\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    parseCmd(d)
  File "D:\Data\vbe\workspace\marsPython\testCircular2\main.py", line 3, in parseCmd
    print(tbl.tblx[d][0])
AttributeError: module 'tbl' has no attribute 'tblx'
```

In C I think I would just tell by declaration in `tbl.py` hey there is function `parseEvnt()`. I would not need to include `myParser` and there would be no circular include.

In python I do not know how to do it.

I read few threads and there is always some wise guy recommending refactorizing. But in this case `parseCmd()` needs to see `tblx` which needs to see `parseEvnt()` (unless function declaration) and `parseEvnt()` need to call `parseCmd()` (cos `evnt` contains triggering `cmd` and I do not want to double the decoding cmd code).

Is there way how to make it working in python?

Comment: I know I did this once when I had to write a recursive descent parser for a school project. I want to say it has to do with the 'from <> import <>' syntax, but I don't have access to what I need to test that right now.

Comment: I don't know how this relates to your bigger project, but the problem here is that you are trying to use `main` as a top level script and import module. That is frequently problematic but in your case its mostly harmless as long as you put all of the top-level executable stuff under a `if __name__ == "__main__":` statement. You end up importing `main` twice (once as `__main__` and once as `main`).

Comment: @tdelaney Indeed. Depending on the project, if the main is supposed to contain executable code, it should only define functions that will be used locally. And since `parseCmd()` is used by more modules, it should be moved to a different file, from where it can be imported as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can frequently get away with circular dependencies as long as the modules don't try to use each other's data until all importing is complete - as a practical matter, that means referencing with namespace (`from module import something` is forbidden) and only using the other modules inside functions and methods (no `mystuff = module.mystuff` in the global space). That's because when importing starts, python puts the module name in `sys.modules` and won't try to import that module again.

You ran into trouble because when you run `main.py`, python adds `__main__` to `sys.modules`. When the code finally came around to `import main`, there was no "main" in the module list and so `main.py` was imported again... and its top level code tried to run.

Lets rearrange your test case and throw in a few print statements to tell when import happens.

**myParser.py**

```
print('  + importing myParser')
import sys

print('import parsecmd')
import parsecmd
def parseEvnt():
    sys.stdout.write("evnt:")
    parsecmd.parseCmd(1)
```

**tbl.py**

```
print('  + importing tbl')
print('import myParser')
import myParser
tblx = {
       1:("cmd",),
       2:("evnt",myParser.parseEvnt),
       }
```

**Parsecmd.py (new)**

```
print('  + importing parsecmd')
print('import tbl')
import tbl
def parseCmd(d):
    print(tbl.tblx[d][0])
```

**main.py**

```
print('running main.py')

print('import parsecmd')
import parsecmd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data=[1,2]
    for d in data:
        if(d<2):
            parsecmd.parseCmd(d)
        else:
            fce = parsecmd.tbl.tblx[d][1]
            fce()
```

When I run it I get

```
running main.py
import parsecmd
  + importing parsecmd
import tbl
  + importing tbl
import myParser
  + importing myParser
import parsecmd                     <-- didn't reimport parsecmd
cmd
evnt:cmd
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually you putting `parseCmd(d)` into `Parsecmd.py` is having same circular dependance: ->`tbl`->`myParser`->`parsecmd`->. What is actually enough to solve the issue is just add one line: `if __name__ == "__main__":`. That was the problem all along!!! I like your demo `print("importXY")`. It makes even a fool (me) understanding what's going on. So once again all wise guys (not you) suggesting refactoring: PYTHON DOES NOT MIND CIRCULAR IMPORT. As long as you realize that import runs the code which is not in function.

Answer (score 2):

Circular imports should be avoided. Refactoring is required, any workaround that still requires a circular import is not a good solution.

That being said, the refactoring doesn't have to be extensive. There are at least a couple of fairly simple solutions.

### Solution 1: move shared functions to a shared module

Since you want to use `parseCmd` from more than one place, move it to a separate file. That way both `main.py` and `myParser.py` can import the function.

### Solution 2: have main pass `parseCmd` to `parseEvnt`.

First, make `parseEvnt` accept an argument to tell it which function to run:

```
# myParser.py
import sys
def parseEvnt(parseCmd):
    sys.stdout.write("evnt:")
    parseCmd(1)
```

Next, when you call `myParser.parseEvnt`, pass in a reference to `main.parseCmd`:

```
# main.py:

...
else:
    fce = tbl.tblx[d][1]
    fce(parseCmd)
```

There are other ways to accomplish the same thing. For example, you could add a "configure" method in `myParser`, and then have `main.py` call the `configure` method and pass in a reference to its `parseCmd`. The `configure` method can then store this reference in a global variable.

Comment: ad solution 1) even if you do `parseCmd`->`tbl`->`myParse`->`parseCmd`. There is logical dependency out of definition of the problem. Evnt contains cmd but is also cmdCode.

Comment: @VitBernatik: I'm sorry, I don't understand that comment.

Comment: ad solution 1) even if you move it to separate file there would be still necessary circular import (`parseCmd`->`tbl`->`myParse`->`parseCmd`). Right? There is logical dependency in the definition of the problem. `tbl` contains `cmd` and `evnt`. `evnt` parser has to use `tbl` again cos the definition of the problem is that `evnt` contains `cmd` (which triggered `evnt`).

Answer (score 2):

Another choice is to import main in the function that uses it:

main.py

```
import sys

def parseEvnt():
    import main
    sys.stdout.write("evnt:")
    main.parseCmd(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're insistent on not refactoring (which is the real solution to this - not being a wise guy), you could move your problematic import into your function in `myParser.py`

```
import sys

def parseEvnt():
    import main  ## import moved into function
    sys.stdout.write("evnt:")
    main.parseCmd(1)
```

Again, see if you can redesign your code so such interdependencies are avoided.

The above solution is sort of a hack and won't solve future problems you might run into due to this dependency.